# How to add custom header per file in multipart upload FormData element

Tags: angular, typescript, multipartform-data, form-data

Is there a way to extend/overload existing [FormData append method in Typescript/Angular](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.formdata.html#get) to be able to provide custom header per file upload?
For example to be able to add **Content-MD5** per each file:

------WebKitFormBoundary9GAg4rr3232
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="file"
Content-Type: image/png
**Content-MD5:MD5Hash**

------WebKitFormBoundary9GAg4r99999
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="file2"
Content-Type: image/png
**Content-MD5:MD5Hash**

Comment: FormData.append('key','value') is used to attach custom backend configs to your payload. Why would you like to override it? Do you mean you want to override the global Angular Http headers instead? I did not get your point

Comment: Not override but extend with custom header per file in FormData/payload, like Content-MD5 in my example, it is requirements from backend service

Comment: I want to have an option to do something like FormData.append('file', blobFile, customHeaders)